# Allocating numbers (x1, x2, x3, ...) to each element in a list (a1, a2, a3, ...) so that a1/x1 is similar to a2/x2 and so on

Tags: algorithm, constraint-programming, minimization

Suppose I have a list of numbers = [3, 10, 20, 1, ...]
How can I assign a number (x1, x2, x3, x4,  ...) to each of the elements in the list, so that 3/x1 ~= 10/x2 ~= 20/x3 ~= 1/x4 = ... ?

Edit: there are some restrictions on the numbers (x1, x2, x3...). they have to be picked from a list of available numbers (which can be floating points as well).
The problem is that the number of elements is not the same. There are more X elements. Xs can be assigned multiple times.

The goal is to minimize the difference between 3/x1, 10/x2, 20/x3, 1/x4

Comment: Do you want your x-values to be (positive) integer numbers? Or are real numbers (floating point) also acceptable?

Comment: You can set `x1` to `1`, and then the other x-values should follow automatically from a basic calculation.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say that there are some restrictions on the numbers (x1, x2, x3...). they have to be picked from a list of available numbers. Please see the edit

Comment: Floating points are acceptable

Comment: The problem is that the number of elements is not the same. There are more X elements than A elements

Comment: I am confused by the terms "similar" and "correct". Do you have to find a solution where all the `a/x` values are the same, or just "close" to each other, and in the latter case, do you need the optimal solution?

Comment: I need the optimal solution

Comment: And how do you define optimality? Where the lowest number of `a/x` pairs deviate from the "common" value, or where the mean (squared) error is smallest? Can you show a concrete example of `a` and `x` arrays for us to get an idea of the dimension and values, and also show the "optimal" solution for that example?

Comment: Optimality here is where the average min distance from all divisions is closer to 0. An array could be of size 5, for example: [1182985.0, 1181419.0, 1183960.0, 1181306.0, 1181457.0]. The available numbers could be, for example [5, 10, 20, 40, 55, 60, 100, ....]

Comment: In this particular example, the numbers in `a` are almost the same, different by about 0.1%, so you are basically just looking for the set of numbers from `x` that have the least (relative) difference. In particular, with the numbers provided, _no_ assignment will give results anywhere _close_ to "similar"...

Comment: And can the `x`s be used multiple times? You are adding more and more information in the comments. Please edit your question instead. Also, what is the average min distance? From the set of quotients, you can either retrieve the minimum or the average. But not both at the same time.

Comment: Yeah I know that in this case the numbers are really similar because I'm still looking for simple programs (it depends on the programs).
The x can be used multiple times. I'll edit everything, sorry. 
I meant the average distance

Comment: Please give one or two illustrative examples.  The one you gave is trivial: you pick the largest `x` value and assign that to every denominator.  Your error measurement will be very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It often helps to develop a mathematical model. E.g.

Let

```
   a(i)>=0  i=1,..,m
   b(j)>0   j=1,..,n with n > m
```

be the data.

Introduce variables (to be determined by the model)

```
   c      =  common number for all expressions to be close to
   x(i,j) =  1 if a(i) is assigned to b(j)
             0 otherwise
```

Then we can write:

```
min sum((i,j), (x(i,j)*(a(i)/b(j) - c))^2 )
subject to
    sum(j, x(i,j)) = 1   for all i  (each a(i) is assigned to exactly one b(j))
    x(i,j) in {0,1}
    c free
```

This is a non-linear model. MINLP (Mixed Integer Non-linear Programming) solvers are readily available. You can also choose an objective that can be linearized:

```
min sum((i,j), abs(x(i,j)*(a(i)/b(j) - y(i,j))) )
subject to
    y(i,j) = x(i,j)*c
    sum(j, x(i,j)) = 1   for all i
    x(i,j) in {0,1}
    c free
```

This can be reformulated as a MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) model. There are many MIP solvers available.

The solution can look like:

[image]

The values inside the matrix are a(i)/b(j). Each row corresponds to an a(i), and has exactly one matching b(j).

More details are [here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2019/06/special-assignment-problem.html).